if $\alpha$ is a curve on the unit sphere then $\kappa'(s)^{2}=\tau(s)^{2}\cdot\kappa(s)^{2}\cdot\left(\kappa(s)^{2}-1\right)$
I am attempting to answer the following question:
given a curvutre on the unit sphere $\alpha$ with arc length parametrization (which means $\forall s:||\alpha(s)||=1$) prove the following:
$\kappa'(s)^{2}=\tau(s)^{2}\cdot\kappa(s)^{2}\cdot\left(\kappa(s)^{2}-1\right)$
EDIT a soultion thanks to @TedShifrin hint:
Since $\overline v,\overline n ,\overline b$ are spanning $\mathbb R^3$ every curve should be a linear combination of them hence we will set:
$\alpha$=$\lambda\overline{v}+\mu\overline{n}+l\overline{b}$
where $\lambda,\mu,l$ are functions of s.
since $|\alpha \cdot \alpha|=1$ if we take the derviative we get $\alpha'\cdot\alpha=0$ and if we take once more we get $\alpha''\cdot\alpha=-1$.
using those two we get:

$0=\alpha'\cdot\alpha=\alpha'\cdot(\lambda\overline{v}+\mu\overline{n}+l\overline{b})=\alpha'(s)\cdot\lambda\overline{v}+\alpha'(s)\cdot\mu\overline{n}+\alpha'(s)\cdot l\overline{b}$

since $\overline b,\overline n$ are ortogonal to $\alpha'=\overline v$:
$0=||\alpha'(s)||\cdot\lambda\implies1\cdot\lambda=0\implies\lambda=0$
so now $\alpha=\mu\overline{n}+l\overline{b}$.
2.we multiplay $\alpha$ by $\alpha''$ and we get:
$-1=\alpha''\cdot\mu\overline{n}+\alpha''\cdot l\overline{b}=\alpha''\cdot\mu\overline{n}+0=\mu\cdot\alpha''\cdot\frac{\alpha''}{||\alpha''||}=\mu\cdot||\alpha''||$
and since $\kappa=||\alpha''||$ we got $\frac{-1}{\kappa}=\mu$.
Hence $\alpha=\frac{-1}{\kappa}\cdot\overline{n}+l\overline{b}$
now we will take the derivative to get:
$\alpha'=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}\cdot\overline{n}-\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\overline{n}'+l'\overline{b}+l\overline{b}'$
using frenet-serret we get:
$\overline{v}=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}\cdot\overline{n}-\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\left(-\kappa\cdot\overline{v}+\tau\cdot\overline{b}\right)+l'\overline{b}+l\cdot\left(-\tau\cdot\overline{n}\right)=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}\cdot\overline{n}+\overline{v}+-\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\tau\cdot\overline{b}+l'\overline{b}-l\cdot\tau\cdot\overline{n}=\overline{v}+\overline{n}\cdot\left(\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}-l\cdot\tau\right)+\overline{b}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\tau+l'\right)$
Now using the fact that $\overline{v}, \overline{n}, \overline b$ are linearly independent we will compare coefficients:
$\begin{cases}
1=1\\
0=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}-l\cdot\tau\implies & l\cdot\tau=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}}\implies l=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}\cdot\tau}\\
0=-\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\tau+l'\implies & l'=\frac{1}{\kappa}\cdot\tau
\end{cases}$
hence we got: $\alpha=\frac{-1}{\kappa}\cdot\overline{n}+\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}\cdot\tau}\cdot\overline{b}$
Now using the fact that $||\alpha||$=1 we get:
$\sqrt{\left(\frac{-1}{\kappa}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^{2}\cdot\tau}\right)^{2}}=1\implies\frac{1}{\kappa^{2}}+\frac{\left(\kappa'\right)^{2}}{\kappa^{4}\cdot\tau^{2}}=1\implies \kappa^{2}\cdot\tau^{2}+\left(\kappa'\right)^{2}=\kappa^{4}\cdot\tau^{2}\implies\left(\kappa'\right)^{2}=\kappa^{4}\cdot\tau^{2}-\kappa^{2}\cdot\tau^{2}$
and we got $\left(\kappa'\right)^{2}=\left(\kappa^{2}\cdot\tau^{2}\right)\cdot\left(\kappa^{2}-1\right)$ as desired.

Stop using the algebraic geometry tag. It has no relevance here. Item 1) is just false in general. What precise is the assumption about the curve $\alpha$? Is it perhaps a curve on the unit sphere? You seem to be working with that. You have done it correctly. The equation $\alpha\cdot\alpha''=-1$ and Cauchy-Schwarz are both correct. Just work more carefully. You do have $\kappa\alpha\cdot n = -1$. What do you know about $|\alpha\cdot n|$? Therefore, taking absolute values, what do you conclude?

@TedShifrin sorry you are right, also it is a curve on the unit sphere

@TedShifrin am I missing something or that $|\alpha\cdot n|$ is as I showed less or equal to 1?

Right. So you get $\kappa\ge 1$ when you take absolute values, right?

@TedShifrin do u mean that this works? $\kappa\cdot|\overline{n}\cdot\alpha(s)|=1$ hence by chuchy sw: $\kappa\cdot|\overline{n}\cdot\alpha(s)|\le\kappa\cdot\left|\sqrt{\cdot||\overline{n}||\cdot||\alpha(s)||}\right|=\kappa$ ?

HINT for 2.: Write $\alpha = \lambda T + \mu N + \nu B$ for some functions $\lambda,\mu,\nu$. Get expressions for $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $\nu$ in terms of $\kappa$ and $\tau$. Make sure to use $\|\alpha\|^2 = 1$.
EDIT: Following up on what you've added to your post. Yes, $\lambda=0$ and $\mu=-1/\kappa$. But you did not write the Frenet equations and use linear independence of $T,N,B$ as I'd suggested. This is an important technique that shows up in lots of exercises.
From $\alpha = \mu N + \nu B$, differentiating and using the Frenet equations gives
$$T=\mu' N + \mu(-\kappa T + \tau B) + \nu' B + \nu(-\tau N),$$
and collecting terms and using linear independence gives
\begin{align*}
1+\mu\kappa &= 0, \\
\mu'-\nu\tau &= 0, \\
\nu'+\mu\tau &=0.
\end{align*}
As you already knew, $\mu=-\frac1\kappa$, but now we have
$$\nu=\frac1\tau\mu' = -\frac1\tau(\frac 1\kappa)'=\frac{\kappa'}{\kappa^2\tau}.$$
We do not need the third displayed equation. Now, as I also suggested previously, what does $\|\alpha\|^2=1$ tell you about $\mu$ and $\nu$?

if u could give another hint I would appreciate that, I understand that since the span of T,N,B is $\mathbb R^3$ every curve would be some linear combanition of those 3 vectors, but trying to get the derviative in order to get $\kappa$ leads to no where as well as using Frenet–Serret formulas lead me to no where

Have you not done standard Frenet-Serret computations? After differentiating, you collect terms and use linear independence of $T,N,B$. You can search and find many, many questions answered on this site about spherical curves.

the most I have done is to deraive those two formulas $\kappa(t)=\frac{||\alpha'\times\alpha''||}{||\alpha'||^{3}},\tau(t)=\frac{\alpha'\cdot\alpha''\times\alpha'''}{||\alpha'\times\alpha''||^{2}}$ , sorry I guess I wasn't really taught about them only shown. I will retry using ur hint, thanks

No, do not use those formulas.

could u give me another hint then maybe?

Read what I wrote in my first hint and then the follow-up comment. Edit your post to include your efforts doing that.

I have edited with my attempt been stuck there since yday

So, this is an improvement. You should in general post your efforts so that people are  better able to help you. You followed part of my advice, but not all of it.

I will revisit it and try again tbh  regardless of the fact someone gave an hint I will try to revisit I do want to "finish the proof my self", I thank u for that hint

I have edited a soultion, I really appreciate your help sadly I feel like I am being taught the subject a bit poorly maybe its a reason I forgot basic stuff like to compare coefficients when the vectors are linearly independant.

I'm glad you finally got the solution and understand it. I don't know what textbook your course is following, but you might find my text, freely available at the link in my profile, occasionally helpful.

First, notice that a curve being on the unit sphere requires that $\alpha\cdot \frac{d\alpha}{ds}=0$. Denoting the curve's natural coordinate system by $(\mathbf{T,N,B})$, we see immediately that the above requirement translates to the curve being orthogonal to its tangent vector. Thus we can write
$$\alpha=\cos\theta(s)\mathbf{N}+\sin\theta(s)\mathbf{B}$$
This parametrization guarantees that $||\alpha||=1$ as well. For the next step, we want to compute $d\alpha/ds$ using this relation. Using the Frenet-Serret equations, we can show that
$$\frac{d\alpha}{ds}=-\kappa\cos\theta\mathbf{T}+(-\tau+\dot{\theta})\sin\theta\mathbf{N}+(\tau-\dot{\theta})\cos\theta\mathbf{B}$$
For this to be the tangent vector, the following relations need to hold
$$\cos\theta=-1/\kappa,~~~ \dot{\theta}=\tau$$
We see that since the curvature and torsion are expressible in terms of a single function $\theta(s)$, they are related to each other. The requisite relation follows by eliminating $\theta$. Taking a derivative in the first relation, squaring and substituting $\sin\theta, \dot{\theta}$ in yields the requisite relation.

Too long for a comment.
OP found  $\alpha\cdot T=0$ and $\alpha\cdot N=-\frac1\kappa$ where $$\alpha'=T$$ and
$$T'=\alpha''=\kappa N.$$
Note that $\kappa\geq1$ since the curve lies on the unit sphere whose curvature is $1$.
Taking derivative of $\alpha\cdot\alpha''=-1$ (OP could have done that) gives $$\alpha'\cdot\alpha''+\alpha\cdot\alpha'''=0$$
$$\require{cancel}\kappa \cancel{T\cdot N}+\alpha\cdot(\kappa N)'=0$$
$$\kappa'\alpha\cdot N+\kappa\alpha\cdot N'=0.$$
By using Frenet-Serret equations for $N'$, we have
$$\kappa'\alpha\cdot N+\kappa\alpha\cdot(\cancel{-\kappa T}+\tau B)=0$$ and
$$\kappa'=-\kappa\tau\frac{\alpha\cdot B}{\alpha\cdot N}=\kappa^2\tau\alpha\cdot B.$$
On the other hand, as explained by Grammatikos and Ted,
$$\alpha\cdot B=\sqrt{1-(\alpha\cdot N)^2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\kappa^2-1}}\kappa.$$
